# Como iniciar Timer.Start de um serviço ao clicar em um botão?

Tags: winforms, vb.net, windows-service

Olá!

É o seguinte, eu tenho uma solução no visual studio que possui dois projetos...
O primeiro projeto é um sistema Windows Form e o segundo projeto é um Windows Service que serve como um sincronizador, pega as informações que está no banco local e envia para o banco de dados web, e em outra máquina ele pega as informações que estão no banco de dados web e salva no banco de dados local, essa sincronização dos dados acontece geralmente a cada 30 minutos ou 1hora dependendo da configuração no cliente.

O que eu gostaria de saber é o seguinte: Existe alguma forma de eu colocar um botão no projeto Windows Form que ative a função Timer.Start() do Serviço a fim dele sincronizar os dados no momento em que for apertado esse botão? sem ter que esperar o tempo configurado?

Eu não estou conseguindo achar algum material que me ajude a fazer esse botão que dispara uma ação do Windows Service que é um projeto diferente do qual vai estar o botão.

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu ficaria muito agradecido.
Lembrando que eu utilizo a linguagem VB.NET no Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se as duas aplicações estão na mesma máquina, você pode manipular elas através de arquivos.

Você faz o seu botão criar um arquivo dentro de uma pasta, que assim que o seu outro aplicativo encontra-lo, ele executa a ação que quiser.

Por exemplo:

Em seu projeto windows service, crie um timer com um intervalo curto apenas verificando a existencia do arquivo.

```
System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer
{
   Interval = 30000,
   Enabled = true,
   AutoReset = true
};
_timer.Elapsed += Init;
_timer.Start();


void Init(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var file = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "my_app_folder", "start_file");
    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        File.Delete(file); //Deleta para não executar novamente na proxima vez que o timer executar
        //IniciaProcesso
    }
}
```

Seria interessante também se fosse gerado uma espécie de token e gravado dentro do arquivo para garantir que o arquivo gerado foi realmente o seu sistema.